# Java - SocketChannel connection timeout

Tags: java

I have a problem while the socket when it find a no route to host. It wait for quite a long. I want to change the connection timeout. The `select(timeout)` method of selector it's useless here. So i wanted to use `channel.connect(address,timeout)` as socket accept, but in API there is no such method. So i call the method from socket like: `channel.socket().connect(address, timeout)` but i get the following exception:
`java.nio.channels.IllegalBlockingModeException`.

How do i put timeout on connection in channels?

Comment: So why do you use SocketChannel if you don't want to use select()? Or have I missed something?

Comment: For nonblocking ability.

Comment: And use it without a Selector?

Comment: unfortunately i need the selector

Comment: i want to use select() but doesn't help the current problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
while (! channel.finishConnect()) {
   <... timer like Thread.sleep() ..>
}
```